# What is a Riemann sum and how do i recognize one?

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

When researching a Riemann sum it is defined as a way to find a definite integral like in the trapezium rule. The only problem is that the sum is defined in terms of f(x) but i haven't seen an example of an actual function inside a Riemann sum.

So the question is how would you spot a Riemann sum in a problem and write it as an indefinite integral?

Comment: A Riemann sum in practice typically looks like something like $\sum_{i=1}^n f \left ( a+\frac{b-a}{n} i \right ) \frac{b-a}{n}$. This converges to $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ as $n \to \infty$ (at least when the situation is nice). In particular what I have written is a right-hand Riemann sum; there are other possibilities which change the choice of points where $f$ gets evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

A typical example might be

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + i^2} $$

You want to write this in the form from Ian's comment with 
$$ \frac{n}{n^2 + i^2} = f\left(a + (b-a)\frac{i}{n}\right) \frac{b-a}{n} $$

Multiplying by $n$, you want 
$$ \frac{n^2}{n^2 + i^2} = (b-a) f\left(a + (b-a)\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
The dependence on $i$ on the right side is only through $i/n$; we can get
that by dividing numerator and denominator by $n^2$.

$$ \frac{1}{1 + (i/n)^2} = (b-a) f\left(a + (b-a)\frac{i}{n}\right) $$

We may as well take $a=0$ and $b=1$, and then this is
$$ \frac{1}{1+(i/n)^2} = f(i/n)$$
i.e.
$$ f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$
So this sum could be written as a Riemann sum for 
$$ \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\; dx $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the second line you introduce a and b. where do you get those from? Or is this just generic form?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are the endpoints of the interval of integration.  They could always be taken to be $0$ and $1$, although in some cases other values might be more convenient.

Comment: ah, so what you equate n/(n^2+i^2) to is a general formula to find the function being integrated so you can choose what ever limits you want. but how would you get this as a function of n?

Comment: Do you mean, how do you find the sum as a closed-form function of $n$?  That's much harder, and often impossible.  All we're doing here by identifying the sum as a Riemann sum is finding the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I thought to find the limit of the Riemann sum i needed to find the function in terms of n and find the limit of that. Are you saying that the limit as $n \to \infty$ of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + i^2}$ is the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $\int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\; dx$?

Comment: No, there is no $x \to \infty$.  I'm saying the limit as $n \to \infty$ of $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{n}{n^2+i^2}$ is $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\; dx$, which happens to be $\pi/4$.

Comment: right, so to estimate the limit of any Riemann sum you use this $f\left(a + (b-a)\frac{i}{n}\right) \frac{b-a}{n}$ to convert the sum into a function choosing the limits a and b then leaving you with $i/n$ which can be replaced by x and then you can evaluate the integral giving you the limit of the Riemann sum